# Solving equations with subscripted variables

Tags: equation-solving, algebra

A student of mine tried:

```
Solve[1/R == 1/Subscript[R, 1] + 1/Subscript[R, 2], R]
```

which did not work. We then tried:

```
Solve[1/R == 1/R1 + 1/R2, R]
```

which gave the correct answer:

```
(* {{R -> (R1 R2)/(R1 + R2)}} *)
```

So, why doesn't `Solve` handle variables with subscripts?

Comment: Well, it sees the `R` inside the `Subscript`, and so it sees three instances of the variable `R` in the equation. Since there are no algebraic rules for extracting `R` from a `Subscript`, `Solve` doesn't know what to do. `Subscript[R, 1]` is not interpreted as being a variable independent of `R`.

Comment: @march is right: `Solve[1/R == 1/Subscript[Rr, 1] + 1/Subscript[Rr, 2], R]` gives the correct result; it's not `Subscript` per se.

Comment: This is why one should only use `Subscript` for printing stuff unless you know what you are doing. Indexing is easier done with `r[i]` etc.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that `R` is a symbol in its own right even when appearing `Subscript`, so that *Mathematica* thinks you're trying to solve for a variable `R` that also appears in the "function" named `Subscript`. It can't "invert" that function and therefore fails to solve for it. You have to avoid this misunderstanding by choosing a different symbol inside `Subscript`, or just using only `String`s when doing subscripts. That's one of the safest approaches. E.g., `Solve[1/R==1/Subscript["R",1]+1/Subscript["R",2],R]` works fine. Caveat: avoid capital single-letter names.

Comment: `Solve[1/Subscript[R,""]==1/Subscript[R,1]+1/Subscript[R,2],Subscript[R,""]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting in version 10 you can used `Indexed` to make use of subscript formatting of list indices.

```
sol = Solve[1/y == 1/Indexed[r, 1] + 1/Indexed[r, 2], y]
(* {{y -> (Indexed[r, {1}] Indexed[r, {2}])/(Indexed[r, {1}] + Indexed[r, {2}])}} *)
```

[image]

You can then replace `r` by its list directly.

```
sol /. r -> {q, w}
(* {{y -> (q w)/(q + w)}} *)
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: PS: If you would like to subscript formatting in your input cell then you can select the `Indexed` function (e.g. `Indexed[r, 1]` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will evaluate in place and show the subscript format of `Indexed`.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) thinks that the `R` in `Subscript[R, 1]`is the same `R` as in the `1/R` term. It's like trying to solve:

```
f[x, 1] + x == 0
```

where the function `f` is unknown. Basically, you should never try to solve for the variable inside of a [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript).

The other answer both switched [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript) to [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed), and more importantly changed the name of the symbol. Using [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed) without changing the name of the subscripted variable would still not have worked:

```
Solve[1/R == 1/Indexed[R, 1] + 1/Indexed[R, 2], R]
```

> Solve::itdim: The variable R has inconsistent dimensionality.
>
> Solve[1/R == 1/Indexed[R, {1}] + 1/Indexed[R, {2}], R]

So, one must change the name of the subscripted variable. Now, since both `R` and `"R"` look the same, you could use a string `R` in the [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript) instead:

```
Solve[1/R == 1/Subscript["R",1] + 1/Subscript["R",2], R] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\left\{R\to \frac{\text{R}_1 \text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\right\}\right\}$

and Mathematica will have no issues.